# Significance of '__name__ ' attribute in python

Tags: functional-programming, python-3.x

1)

Below python code,

```
>>> def f():
    return
```

creates a `function` type object which has `__name__` attribute with value `'f'` which looks fine.

But,

2)

Below line of code,

```
>>> x = 1024
```

creates  `int` type object but does not have `__name__` attribute.

3)

`lambda` expressions in python also does not associate any unique name for a `function` type object.

```
>>> square = lambda x: x * x
>>> square.__name__
'<lambda>'
>>> summation = lambda x: x + 2
>>> summation.__name__
'<lambda>'
>>>
```

For any program written using Functional paradigm, it  is considered an environment with name-object bindings in that environment.

So, Being functional paradigm programming beginner, How do I understand the significance of `__name__` attribute? Why do I see such inconsistency in second and third case above in not maintaining `__name__` attribute of an object?

Comment: Note that *having an attribute* `__name__` is **utterly unrelated** to *"name-object bindings"* - you have assigned e.g. the `lambda` to the name `square`, through which you can now access it. The `__name__` attribute for functions isn't even necessarily useful, as the function could be subsequently referenced by other names (`f2 = f`) and dereferenced from its original `__name__` (`f = None`). It's worth reading [this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for more on Python names.

Answer (score 2):

What inconsistency?

In the first case, you have a function. In the second case, you have a lambda expression, that is a function which has no name.

Python could have chosen one of those three approaches:

1. Returning `None`,
2. Returning an arbitrary string, such as `<lambda>`,
3. Raising an exception.

All three options are valid, given that the third one will result a `try/except` instead of an `if/else`. Python have chosen the second option. Why would you consider two others being more consistent?

Comment: lambda expressions are used as part of functional paradigm programming. functional paradigm is considered as environment with (name,object) bindings as mentioned in the query.

Comment: Python is not a functional language.

Comment: As [the Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) puts it (emphasis mine): *"Python is a multi-paradigm programming language: object-oriented programming and structured programming are fully supported, and **there are a number of language features which support functional programming** and aspect-oriented programming (including by metaprogramming and by magic methods)... The design of Python offers **only limited support for functional programming** in the Lisp tradition."*